# docker-compose build error for nodejs and yarn: [gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.]

Tags: macos, docker, macbook-air, docker-compose

I have been trying to get a project to work for my job. I recently got a M1 Air, however I had a similar issues when I was doing the same thing on a Windows machine with WSL. The error is as follows:

```
    #8 8.455 ## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
#8 8.455      curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null
#8 8.455      echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
#8 8.455      sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
#8 8.455
#8 8.455
#8 8.455 + apt-get install -y nodejs
#8 8.462 Reading package lists...
#8 8.805 Building dependency tree...
#8 8.871 Reading state information...
#8 8.942 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#8 8.942   nodejs
#8 9.093 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#8 9.093 Need to get 24.5 MB of archives.
#8 9.093 After this operation, 121 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#8 9.093 Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x buster/main arm64 nodejs arm64 14.18.2-deb-1nodesource1 [24.5 MB]
#8 12.29 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#8 12.30 Fetched 24.5 MB in 3s (7,533 kB/s)
#8 12.32 Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 23271 files and directories currently installed.)
#8 12.33 Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_14.18.2-deb-1nodesource1_arm64.deb ...
#8 12.33 Unpacking nodejs (14.18.2-deb-1nodesource1) ...
#8 13.92 Setting up nodejs (14.18.2-deb-1nodesource1) ...
#8 13.94 + curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg
#8 13.94 + apt-key add -
#8 13.97 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
#8 14.39 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -oeux pipefail -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -  &&   apt-get install -y nodejs &&   curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - &&   echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list &&   apt-get update && apt-get install yarn]: exit code: 2
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Has anyone experienced a similar thing?
Here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-buster
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-oeux", "pipefail", "-c"]

# timezone environment
ENV TZ=UTC \
  # locale
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
  LANGUAGE=en_US:en \
  LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
  # composer environment
  COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
  COMPOSER_HOME=/composer \
  # Laravel environment
  APP_SERVICES_CACHE=/tmp/cache/services.php \
  APP_PACKAGES_CACHE=/tmp/cache/packages.php \
  APP_CONFIG_CACHE=/tmp/cache/config.php \
  APP_ROUTES_CACHE=/tmp/cache/routes.php \
  APP_EVENTS_CACHE=/tmp/cache/events.php \
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH=/tmp/cache/views

COPY --from=composer:1.10 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install git libicu-dev libonig-dev libzip-dev unzip locales libpq-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev imagemagick libmagickwand-dev && \
  pecl install imagick && \
  docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \
  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ && \
  docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_pgsql && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
  localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8 && \
  mkdir /var/run/php-fpm && \
  mkdir -p /tmp/cache/views && \
  chmod 777 -R /tmp/cache && \
  docker-php-ext-install intl pdo_mysql zip bcmath && \
  composer config -g process-timeout 3600 && \
  composer config -g repos.packagist composer https://packagist.org && \
  composer global require hirak/prestissimo

# node and yarn
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -  && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs && \
  curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install yarn

RUN yarn global add secure-spreadsheet

COPY ./php-fpm.d/backend-www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz-www.conf
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

WORKDIR /work/backend
```

I tried a solution that I found by [googling](https://halkyo.com/web/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found/) but ended up getting a different error that says:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 41: unknown instruction: APT-GET ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

I also posted for help on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/r8rnqz/help_dockercompose_build_error_for_nodejs_and/) a bit ago hoping to get a faster answer to my problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: The problem was that the pubkey for the yarn package could not be read so the solution was to add this line.

```
RUN cat pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
```

Thanks to VictorXLR on [github](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5864#issuecomment-902137192).